# Android. Push up content when clicking in edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I have a login form on my activity. I need this logic:

http://www.clipular.com/c/6455748191322112.png?k=Xc28Y-FsMShuNpEXbWD5rpe6faY
http://www.clipular.com/c/5414772807041024.png?k=k3TB9AiHEtdV8oh6G17Ag-MS2nI

How I can do this? I have tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the `Activity` in the manifest but this did not work.

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/truck">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/login_logo_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/login_logo_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_logo_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/login_logo_margin_left"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_transfort_white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        style="@style/GrayText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_text_height"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/skip_button_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/skip_button_margin_top"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/skip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputs"
        android:background="@drawable/login_buttons_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/default_text_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
            android:background="@color/text_color_white_transparent"
            android:ems="16"
            android:hint="@string/login"
            style="@style/LoginInputs"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/inputs_line"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/login_line_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_line_margin_top"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
            android:background="@color/line_color_white_capacity" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/default_text_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_line_margin_top"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
            android:background="@color/text_color_white_transparent"
            android:ems="16"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            style="@style/LoginInputs" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_text_height"
        android:layout_below="@id/inputs"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/forgot_password_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/WhiteText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter"
        android:background="@drawable/sigin_button_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/forgot_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/signin_button_margin_top"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/enter_text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/enter"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/no_account_margin_left"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/no_account_margin_top"
            android:text="@string/no_account"
            style="@style/GrayText"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/check_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/check_in_margin_left"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/no_account_margin_top"
            android:text="@string/check_in"
            style="@style/WhiteText" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do one thing add  two button when you  listen the keyboard open close and hide and show according to keyboard open close

Comment: And one more thing... I have only image of truck, this image without black part at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

make `ScrollView` as parent Layout

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

        // add here all your controls

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

than use

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in you activity

```
<activity
     android:name=".activity.TempActivity"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/truck"
        android:contentDescription="@string/truck" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/auth_gradient_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gradient" />
</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</View>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/login_logo_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/login_logo_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_logo_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/login_logo_margin_left"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_transfort_white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        style="@style/GrayText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_text_height"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/skip_button_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/skip_button_margin_top"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/skip" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputs"
                android:background="@drawable/login_buttons_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/login"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/default_text_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                    android:background="@color/text_color_white_transparent"
                    android:ems="16"
                    android:hint="@string/login"
                    style="@style/LoginInputs"/>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/inputs_line"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/login_line_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_line_margin_top"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                    android:background="@color/line_color_white_capacity" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/default_text_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_line_margin_top"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                    android:background="@color/text_color_white_transparent"
                    android:ems="16"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    style="@style/LoginInputs" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/error_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/default_text_height"
                android:layout_below="@id/inputs"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/forgot_password_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                tools:text="@string/auth_error"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/RedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/default_text_height"
                android:layout_below="@id/inputs"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/forgot_password_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/WhiteText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/enter"
                android:background="@drawable/sigin_button_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/forgot_password"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/inputs_block_margin_left_right"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/signin_button_margin_top"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/enter_text" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/enter"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/no_account"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/no_account_margin_left"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/no_account_margin_top"
                    android:text="@string/no_account"
                    style="@style/GrayText"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/check_in"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/check_in_margin_left"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/no_account_margin_top"
                    android:text="@string/check_in"
                    style="@style/WhiteText" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But in this case I need to scroll to the button from the code when keyboard is show/hide